# How to handle IE security alert pop up in Selenium

Tags: selenium, alert

I am getting "Alert data: When you send information to the Internet, it might be possible for others to see that information. Do you want to continue?" while running the login script. I am able to capture the security alert data but not able to accept that alert and proceed further.

```
@Test
  public void f() 
  {
    driver.get("http://www.demo.guru99.com/V4/");  
    String title= driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println(title);
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input"));
        element.sendKeys("mngr57377");
        WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input"));
        element1.sendKeys("yzUdAtu");
        WebElement elementClick=driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input[1]"));
        elementClick.click();
        try {
            click(elementClick);
        } catch (UnhandledAlertException f) {
            try {
                Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
                alert.accept();
                String alertText = alert.getText();
                System.out.println("Alert data: " + alertText);

            } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

  }
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any alert. which IE version you are using ?

Comment: I am using IE11

Comment: I'm also using same version. it is not showing any alert. The reason may be security settings of your IE

Comment: Okay..
But If we want to handle that alert in selenium then how to script it??

Comment: can you add the snap of that alert

Comment: I have tried scripting that..I am able to get the alert data but not able to accept that alert and proceed further. The script is getting abort after that point.

Comment: I am not able to upload the image as I need to have 10 reputation points for uploading the images

Answer (score 0):

As per your code  `click(elementClick);` is wrong under try block. I think you have to go in this way -

After login button click use following code to handle the alert -

```
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input"));
    element.sendKeys("mngr57377");
    WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input"));
    element1.sendKeys("yzUdAtu");
    WebElement elementClick=driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input[1]"));
    elementClick.click();
    try 
    {

        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        alert.accept();
        String alertText = alert.getText();
        System.out.println("Alert data: " + alertText);

    }
    catch (NoAlertPresentException e)
    {
         e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

And the another thing, try to avoid using `absolute xpath` instead of that use `relative xpath` or try to make your customized xpath.